# JavaScript mootools addEvent

Tags: javascript, mootools, addeventlistener

I am trying to find what's wrong with my code.
Mootools core file is attached to HTML head and works well.

If I add the code:

```js
$('myElement').addEvent('click', function(){
    alert('clicked!');
});
```

right below the `<div id="myElement">Click me</div>` then it works.

But if I add it to the separate javascript.js file then it does not work

HTML is this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
<head>   
<script type="text/javascript" src="mootools-core-1.4.5-full-nocompat.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>  
</head>
<body>  
<div id="myElement">Click me.</div>
</body>  
</html>
```

And javascript.js is this:

```js
$('myElement').addEvent('click', function(){
    alert('clicked!');
});
```

All files (html, mootools-core and javascript.js are in the same directory).
Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to wrap the expression in a [`domready` event](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Utilities/DOMReady):

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    $('myElement').addEvent('click', function() {
        alert('clicked!');
    });
});
```