# MooTools - adding next and previous buttons

Tags: javascript, mootools

I have a working gallery with functional thumbnail navigation, but I'd like to add `next` and `previous` buttons as well, but can't seem to figure it out. I've never used MooTools before so it's proved to be a little tricky since I am modifying a wordpress plugin. It appears to be using MooTools core, Fx.Scroll and Scroller.

It's the NextGen Scroll Gallery plugin and the gallery can be seen here: [Gallery](http://rnld.ndmr.com/)

I tried using the method like the first one found here: [Scroller Demo](http://damien.degois.info/projects/mootools-scroller/Demo/demo.html)

I also tried adding variations of `addEvent` at line 213 of scrollGallery.js

Then, I went here and tried it this way: [MooTools addEvent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11629131/javascript-mootools-addevent)

Finally, I tried `prev()` and `next()`, `scrollToImg(index+1)`, and `activeImgNum+1`, but would either get nothing or an undefined error.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**
Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stinkysGTI/mpmfeojo/1/)

And it's MooTools v1.3.2

Comment: your code would help

Comment: Please make a jsFiddle reproducing your problem and add here the info about which MooTools version you are using.

Comment: I added a fiddle and mootools version